# Can I remove a photo or video from the Memories feature in iOS 10's photo app?

Tags: photos, ios

I love the new memories feature in iOS 10 but sometimes it grabs less than great photos. Can I remove those photos just from the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, tap the edit button in the lower right corner than select the 'Photos & Videos" item to remove or add media to a memory. It is also broken out on [MacRumor's guide](http://www.macrumors.com/how-to/ios-10-photos-edit-memories/).